# Provide array of URNs to LinkedIn REST API?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn Marketing Development Platform where I am trying to provide a list of company URNs to to the Ad Analytics API. However, when I try to provide a list of company URNs, it fails with status 400.

[Analytics Finder endpoint docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#analytics-finder)

My request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2017&timeGranularity=ALL&companies=urn:li:organization:1234,urn:li:organization:5678
```

Response:

```
{"message":"Array parameter 'companies' value 'urn:li:organization:1234,urn:li:organization:5678' is invalid. Reason: Deserializing output 'urn:li:organization:1234,urn:li:organization:5678' failed","status":400}
```

I have also tried URL encoding the URL, and providing the list via the parameter `companies[0]` as is done in other examples in the docs.

What is the correct way to input arrays to the LinkedIn API?

Edit: Changed `accounts` to `companies`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the [Protocol Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-multiple-shares) actually gave me some useful insight. There are a couple of ways of providing arrays in parameters.

From the docs:

For Restli V1.0 (used by default)

```
GET GET https://api.linkedin.com/people?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
```

For Restli V2.0, which you can use by setting the following header: `X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0`

Pass parameters in List format.

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?ids=List(1,2,3,4)
```

However, I have not managed to get the Analytics Finder API to work with Restli V2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide the list of URL encoded organization URNs to the `accounts` param. Using your request as an example:

`&accounts=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A1234,urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A5678)`

Comment: While this method makes sense, it doesn't seem to work with this specific endpoint. See my answer for alternatives.

Comment: @lotm You need to pass the following header to allow RestLi v2 format:

```X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0```

Comment: Thank you I tried it, but now it seems to be complaining about the formatting of the date... Could you perhaps advise how the date should be formatted in RestLi v2 format?

Comment: Have you tried using this format for the date object?

```dateRange=(start:(day:28,month:7,year:2019))```